# javascript match expression Expected "/" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, match

I am receiving the following error below in all IE versions. Works in other browsers. I have searched around but unable to find a workaround.

console error: Expect "/"

It looks like it's failing on all my match statements. Here is one example:

```
    function checkURL(linkUrl){
        var match1 = /infomanagerdoc[^]*\/topic\/([0-9]+)/;          

        return ( linkUrl.match(match1) );
    }
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this.

Comment: You have not closed your `[character class]`. Character classes cannot be empty, so when the first character is `]` then it is treated as a literal. Did you mean `[^\/]*`?

Comment: I can't get it to throw that error in the console for IE10. [^] does look weird to me though. not sure what it's purpose is

Comment: no I'm search for `\/topic\/` so i am denoting the forward slash as special character.

Comment: `[^]` is to match anything in between